# Image Upload and manipulation API taking more time for higher resolution images

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Current flow that I am following for *image* `upload` and its `manipulation` on the [S3 bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) is as follows:

1. Image is uploaded into an [S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html).
2. Retrieving the image buffer of the saved image in the [S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html).
3. Resizing of the image buffer using [gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html) and [imagemagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick) npm module.
4. Saving the resized image buffer with the original extension as a new image in the [S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html).

As the `image size` increases so those the API `response` time.It takes *3* secs for the API to give a response while following above workflow for a 300 KB image and 30 secs for a 15 MB or more image.

I don't know if my flow is correct or not. My requirement is that I need to reduce my API response time while uploading a 15 or more MB image. Can somebody suggest me how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

To make it clear I am uploading a single 15 MB file which I am sending it from `Advanced Rest Client` (a chrome plugin) to my API. The image file is currently present in my local system. I am currently working on `jpg` and `png` images.  I want to resize the image to both bigger and smaller sizes by *reducing the width to height ratio*. The API that I Have written is in Node JS which follows the above workflow.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want to send a 15MB image to S3 (from where?), and process it on S3 (or somewhere else?). You want to resize it - bigger or smaller? JPEG or PNG? by reducing the quality or the dimensions? You then want to write it back to S3. There is an API involved somewhere - what API ? an aws-cli API? a web API for some unknown website? You are surprised that big images take longer? Do you have multiple images or just one?

Comment: @Mark Setchell  I have edited my Post to answer your questions. Please provide ur valuable suggestion to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like upload and download big image from S3 takes a lot of time.

You can do some optimizations:

- Try to use `graphicsmagick` package, in common cases it's faster that imagemagick (latest versions)
- Make resize / optimize operations before
  uploading to S3 and upload at last step
- If it's not possible - try to use Streams for downloading - resizing - uploading to S3. just pipe request stream to gm module and write pipe to AWS S3
- Make image optimizations from Amazon EC2 infastructure, it's having
  very high network perfomance with S3

Comment: Hi Vmkcom, Do you have any idea how do I take a local image, convert it into a Buffer or stream and then Resize it based on my requirement using image Magik?